# Ubuntu system drops to BusyBox prompt while booting, followed by "udevd [94]: timeout: killing '/ sbin / blkid-o udev-p / dev / sda' " error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, udev, busybox

I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 on a netbook (Intel 1.6 GHz and RAM 1 GB) with Windows XP. One week ago, Ubuntu stopped. That day had not installed any upgrade or any software.

When I try to start Ubuntu, I get is this message:

```
BusyBox v1.18.4 (Ubuntu 1:1.18.4-2ubuntu2) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(Initramfs)
```

After a few seconds, I get the following error:

```
(Initramfs) udevd [94]: timeout '/ sbin / blkid-o udev-p / dev / sda'

udevd [94]: timeout: killing '/ sbin / blkid-o udev-p / dev / sda' [144]
```

The second of these lines begins to repeat a lot of times, until finally it appears this line:

```
udevd [94]: '/ sbin / blkid-o udev-p / dev / sda' [144] terminated by signal 9 (Killed)
```

Then the computer is locked and the only way I know to get out is by pressing CTRL+ALT+DEL to return to GRUB, boot Windows and close Windows.

For better understanding, I leave screenshots (click to enlarge):

http://s2.subirimagenes.com/fotos/7452362udev1.jpg 
http://s2.subirimagenes.com/fotos/7452375udev4.jpg

This is my partition table disk:

- `/dev/sda1 → swap`
- `/dev/sda2 → /`, ext4
- `/dev/sda3 → /windows`, ntfs
- `/dev/sda4 → /shared`, fat32

I run "chkdsk" from Windows to check the Windows partitions (`/dev/sda3` and `/dev/sda4`) and the result has been successful: no errors were found.

Then I tried booting Ubuntu in recovery mode and using previous versions of the kernel, but in all cases I have had the same error. Then I did a memory test (two passes) and no errors were found.

Finally I tried to start the netbook from a Live USB of Ubuntu 11.10 (created with UNetbootin), but I get the same error when I try to boot my Ubuntu installation from GRUB:

```
udevd [94]: timeout: killing '/ sbin / blkid-o udev-p / dev / sda' [144]
```

I think I have a hardware failure on the hard drive, but I don't understand why this affects only the Linux partition and not the Windows partition.

I don't know what else I can do.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the system could not find or mount the partition holding the root filesystem.

The [BusyBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox) prompt is part of the [initial RAM disk (`initramfs`)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initrd), which is normally used in the early stages of booting Linux, before the root filesystem is loaded.  This `initramfs`, along with the kernel and GRUB (bootloader) data, is typically stored in a separate boot partition.  It appears your boot partition is intact.

`blkid` is responsible for scanning the hard drive and conveying partition information to `udev` so that it can mount the partitions.  Apparently, `blkid` hung or took too long while scanning for the root partition, so the system killed `blkid` and the root filesystem could not be mounted.  This can be caused by a faulty hard drive or damaged partition data.

There are several things you can do:

- Make sure that the root partition is correctly specified on the bootloader.
- Use [`badblocks`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Badblocks) to perform a surface scan on the hard drive, using a utility such as [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php), and attempt to repair the root partition if it is damaged.

  - If the hard drive is OK, attempt to recover data from the partition, then delete the partition and reinstall Ubuntu, creating a new partition in its place.
  - If the hard drive has bad blocks, back up all data on the hard drive and replace the drive.  The drive is likely to catastrophically fail in this case.

**Edit:**  It appears the hard drive has failed.  If the data is valuable, send it to a data recovery service.  Replace the hard drive and restore data from backups, if available.

Comment: I don't know about not *finding* the root partition - the kernel always gave me `Unable to mount rootfs` when I mistyped the `root=` paramater into GRUB. I don't keep up with how Ubuntu does things, though.

Comment: @DragonLord Thank you very much for your educational response :-) But how can I make sure the root partition is correctly specified on the bootloader?

Comment: I started the netbook with PartedMagic 2012.2.19 USB-Live, but does not load the hard drive. When I open GParted, after much time trying to access the disk, I received an error message telling me that it can't find the disk:

http://www.subirimagenes.com/fotos-parted2-7477418.html

What else I can do? Thank you very much!

Comment: @DragonLord I see that the hard drive has failed. I have already recovered data because I have access to the shared partition from Windows. Thank you very much for your help!